# is there any solution for horizontal and vertical header in MUI DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, json, material-ui, datagrid

[Here table is Horizontal Growing and also Vertical,
Vertically by name, and Horizontally by date,
is there any solution to show the data in DataGrid of MUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuXnl.png)

[I am expecting this output in data grid which is in Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6l8d.png)my data is as following,

Here are users array which contain todays attendance status of employee so i need to arrange data vertically by employee name and horizontally by date in mui DataGrid or Table to export into excel

please help me to iterate data and show in table to export like above image

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d357"
  },
  "date": {
    "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.736Z"
  },
  "users": [
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "64099c6c866d8d19fda95b08"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.779Z"
      },
      "designation": "Site Incharge",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d358"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ac0a3e80b774e306d215"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.779Z"
      },
      "designation": "Software developer",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d359"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ac433e80b774e306d218"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.779Z"
      },
      "designation": "Asst Manager - HIS (Non Clinical)",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d35a"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ac763e80b774e306d21b"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.779Z"
      },
      "designation": "Asst Manager - HIS (Clinical)",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d35b"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416acc73e80b774e306d21d"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.779Z"
      },
      "designation": "Asst Manager - PACS cum HIS",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d35c"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ad123e80b774e306d221"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.779Z"
      },
      "designation": "Asst Manager - System Admin cum DBA cum HIS",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d35d"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ad263e80b774e306d224"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.780Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d35e"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ad773e80b774e306d22a"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.780Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d35f"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ae193e80b774e306d236"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.781Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d360"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ae483e80b774e306d239"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.781Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d361"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ae7f3e80b774e306d23c"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.781Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d362"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416aeb33e80b774e306d23f"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.781Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d363"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416aefd3e80b774e306d242"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.781Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d364"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416af1d3e80b774e306d245"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.781Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d365"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416af403e80b774e306d248"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.781Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d366"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416af863e80b774e306d24b"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.782Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d367"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416afb13e80b774e306d24e"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.782Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d368"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416afd53e80b774e306d251"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.782Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d369"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416b00d3e80b774e306d254"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.782Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d36a"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416b0443e80b774e306d257"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.782Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d36b"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416b0693e80b774e306d25a"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.782Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support (MIS Executive)",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d36c"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6458b29392a1a5878c73b63d"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-09T05:31:34.782Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": null,
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645b2c3a9cd35662d771d36d"
      }
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c439f"
  },
  "date": {
    "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.239Z"
  },
  "users": [
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "64099c6c866d8d19fda95b08"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.282Z"
      },
      "designation": "Site Incharge",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43a0"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ac0a3e80b774e306d215"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.283Z"
      },
      "designation": "Software developer",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43a1"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ac433e80b774e306d218"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.283Z"
      },
      "designation": "Asst Manager - HIS (Non Clinical)",
      "status": "L",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43a2"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ac763e80b774e306d21b"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.283Z"
      },
      "designation": "Asst Manager - HIS (Clinical)",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43a3"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416acc73e80b774e306d21d"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.283Z"
      },
      "designation": "Asst Manager - PACS cum HIS",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43a4"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ad123e80b774e306d221"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.284Z"
      },
      "designation": "Asst Manager - System Admin cum DBA cum HIS",
      "status": "L",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43a5"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ad263e80b774e306d224"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.284Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD M",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43a6"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ad773e80b774e306d22a"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.284Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD M",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43a7"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ae193e80b774e306d236"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.284Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD N",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43a8"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ae483e80b774e306d239"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.285Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD M",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43a9"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ae7f3e80b774e306d23c"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.285Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD M",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43aa"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416aeb33e80b774e306d23f"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.285Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD A",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43ab"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416aefd3e80b774e306d242"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.285Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD A",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43ac"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416af1d3e80b774e306d245"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.286Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD N",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43ad"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416af403e80b774e306d248"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.286Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "Ab",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43ae"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416af863e80b774e306d24b"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.287Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FL",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43af"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416afb13e80b774e306d24e"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.287Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "WO",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43b0"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416afd53e80b774e306d251"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.287Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD M",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43b1"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416b00d3e80b774e306d254"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.287Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FL",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43b2"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416b0443e80b774e306d257"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.287Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD A",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43b3"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416b0693e80b774e306d25a"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.288Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support (MIS Executive)",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43b4"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6458b29392a1a5878c73b63d"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-10T11:36:00.288Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645cd494f41c8459dd3c43b5"
      }
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4585"
  },
  "date": {
    "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.710Z"
  },
  "users": [
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "64099c6c866d8d19fda95b08"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.836Z"
      },
      "designation": "Site Incharge",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4586"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ac0a3e80b774e306d215"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.837Z"
      },
      "designation": "Software developer",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4587"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ac433e80b774e306d218"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.837Z"
      },
      "designation": "Asst Manager - HIS (Non Clinical)",
      "status": "L",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4588"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ac763e80b774e306d21b"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.837Z"
      },
      "designation": "Asst Manager - HIS (Clinical)",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4589"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416acc73e80b774e306d21d"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.838Z"
      },
      "designation": "Asst Manager - PACS cum HIS",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c458a"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ad123e80b774e306d221"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.838Z"
      },
      "designation": "Asst Manager - System Admin cum DBA cum HIS",
      "status": "L",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c458b"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ad263e80b774e306d224"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.838Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD A",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c458c"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ad773e80b774e306d22a"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.838Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD A",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c458d"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ae193e80b774e306d236"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.839Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD N",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c458e"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ae483e80b774e306d239"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.839Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "WO",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c458f"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416ae7f3e80b774e306d23c"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.839Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD M",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4590"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416aeb33e80b774e306d23f"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.839Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FL",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4591"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416aefd3e80b774e306d242"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.840Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD M",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4592"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416af1d3e80b774e306d245"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.840Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD N",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4593"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416af403e80b774e306d248"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.840Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "Ab",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4594"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416af863e80b774e306d24b"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.840Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD M",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4595"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416afb13e80b774e306d24e"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.840Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD M",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4596"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416afd53e80b774e306d251"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.841Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD M",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4597"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416b00d3e80b774e306d254"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.841Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD A",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4598"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416b0443e80b774e306d257"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.841Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "WO",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c4599"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6416b0693e80b774e306d25a"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.841Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support (MIS Executive)",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c459a"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6458b29392a1a5878c73b63d"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-05-11T04:19:10.841Z"
      },
      "designation": "IT Executive - Applictaion & Infrastructure Support",
      "status": "FD G",
      "shift": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "645dbea5f41c8459dd3c459b"
      }
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}]
```

Comment: Is it possible to trim down your code, there's a lot of repetitive/ similar user arrays so just giving a sample will help in making your question more concise.